# finding and replacing a string within a line with an if statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement, replace

I am trying to parse a particular text file. I am trying to open the text file and line by line ask if a particular string is there (In the following example case its the presence of the number 01 in the curly brackets), then manipulate a particular string either forwards backwards, or keep it the same. Here's that example, with one line named arbitrarily "go"... (other lines in the full file have similar format but have `{01}, {00}` etc...

```
go = 'USC_45774-1111-0     <hkxhk> {10} ; 78'

go = go.replace(go[22:24],go[23:21:-1])

>>> go
'USC_45774-1111-0     <khxkh> {10} ; 78'
```

I am trying to manipulate the first `"hk" (go[22:24])` by replacing it with the same letters but backwards `(go[23:21:-1)`.What I want is to see `khxhk` but as you can see, the result I am getting is that both are turned backwards to `khxkh`.

I am also having a problem of executing the specific if statement for each line. Many lines that dont have `{01}` are being manipulated as if they were....

```
with open('c:/LG 1A.txt', 'r') as rfp:
with open('C:/output5.txt', 'w') as wfp:
    for line in rfp.readlines():
        if "{01}" or "{-1}" in line:
            line = line.replace(line[25:27],line[26:24:-1])   
            line = line.replace("<"," ")
            line = line.replace(">"," ")
            line = line.replace("x","   ")
            wfp.write(line)

        elif "{10}" or "{1-}" in line:
            line = line.replace(line[22:24],line[23:21:-1])   
            line = line.replace("<"," ")
            line = line.replace(">"," ")
            line = line.replace("x","   ")
            wfp.write(line)

        elif "{11}" in line:
            line = line.replace(line[22:27],line[26:21:-1])   
            line = line.replace("<"," ")
            line = line.replace(">"," ")
            line = line.replace("x","   ")
            wfp.write(line)

    wfp.close()
```

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

The string `replace` method does not replace characters by position, it replaces them by what characters they are.

```
>>> 'apple aardvark'.replace('a', '!')
'!pple !!rdv!rk'
```

So in your first case, you are telling to replace "hk" with "kh".  It doesn't "know" that you want to only replace one of the occurrences; it just knows you want to replace "hk" with "kh", so it replaces all occurrences.

You can use the `count` argument to replace to specify that you only want to replace the first occurrence:

```
>>> go = 'USC_45774-1111-0     <hkxhk> {10} ; 78'
... go.replace(go[22:24],go[23:21:-1],1)
'USC_45774-1111-0     <khxhk> {10} ; 78'
```

Note, though, that this will always replace the *first* occurrence, not necessarily the occurrence at the position in the string you specified.  In this case I guess that's what you want, but it may not work directly for other similar tasks.  (That is, there is no way to use this method as-is to replace the second occurrence or the third occurrence; you can only replace the first, or the first two, or the first three, etc.  To replace the second or third occurrence you'd need to do a bit more.)

As for the second part of your question, you are misunderstanding what `if "{01}" or "{-1}" in line` means.  It means, in layman's terms, `if "{01}" or if "{-1}" in line`.  Since `if "{01}"` is always true (i.e., the string "{01}" is not a false value), the whole condition is always true.  What you want is `if "{01}" in line or "{-1}" in line"`.

Comment: I sometimes want to replace only the second instance.  For example, this is a usual few lines of the text file                                                                                                                 'Cg200                <abxcd> {10} ; 34                           USC_1320-496-0       <hkxhk> {01} ; 51'                              In line 1, the change should be ab to ba only because of the {01},while in line 2 the change should be hk to kh for the second instance only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it is about Python, but your problem is one that gets posted here at least a couple times every day.

```
if "{01}" or "{-1}" in line:
```

This doesn't do what you think it does. It asks, "is `"{01}"` true"?  Because it's a non-zero-length string, it is.  Because `or` short-circuits, the rest of the condition is not tested because the first argument is true.  Therefore the body of your `if` statement is always executed.

In other words, Python evaluates as if you'd written this:

```
if ("{01}") or ("{-1}" in line):
```

You want something like:

```
if "{01}" in line or "{-1}" in line:
```

Or if you have a lot of similar conditions:

```
if any(x in line for x in ("{01}", "{-1}")):
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count argument of `replace()`:

```
'USC_45774-1111-0     <hkxhk> {10} ; 78'.replace("hk","kh",1)
```

For your second question, you need change the condition to:

```
if "{01}" in line or "{-1}" in line:
    ...
```